# I have two websites on one host & one of them redirects to the other one and gives a 301 status code

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I've designed two wordpress websites and have put them both in one host.
now, one of the website's url redirects to the other one.
developer tools shows "status code:301 moved permanently" and "x-redirected-by: wordpress"
I have no idea where to look for the problem.
https://gcatalyst.org/
https://madtlabs.com/
thank you

Answer (score -1):

When you put both websites in one hosting take care that you have pointed the document root correctly from the hosting panel for both the domains to their respective wordpress installation folders. Also check the .htaccess files in the root if you have any existing redirection setup there or not.